# React Native App to foreground when in the background action is successful

Tags: android, react-native

I have a React Native application working. The Application works in the background too.

When my device receives an incoming call it fetches the number and runs this trough my own API. This works, but when there is a result, I want my App to open to the foreground and show the result. Now I have to manually switch to the Application and see the result.

The App already shows a notification when the action is triggered, but that is not what I want. I want the full App to open.

I cannot use higher Android API as 25. Otherwise Androids Foreground Service was an option, but that uses API 26+.

Comment: you can display a notification with the result instead...

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing already, but now that I want. Because the info does not fit in a small notification. @HendEl-Sahli

Comment: you could provide `bigText` prop of you notification to display when the user expands the notification ... you could also make the notification `clickable` and open your app `onNotificationClick` ... cause I think bringing the app to the foreground is not good in terms of user-experience (even if it's achievable) @user1469734

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli I know, but that is not what I want.